# Extended Monitor Mode With Hdmi To DisplayPort Converter

Tags: monitor, displayport

my laptop is Ideapad L3, and I have two monitors with DisplayPort connections (Laptop HDMI to DP converter -> Dell u2419h DP -> Dell u2417h DP).

Problem:
I need extended mode for both monitors, but currently, they are in mirror mode.

Ubuntu only detects one of the monitors.

```
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

GPU: GeForce MX330
```

Display Info:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1366,768
       resources: irq:127 memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP108M [GeForce MX330]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
```

Comment: @guiverc Thanks. I added more information to the issue.